# Local cURL Not Working on www Subdomain, Ubuntu 18.04, GCE

Tags: dns, nginx, curl, wordpress, resolv.conf

I have a VPS on GCE running WordPress and Nginx under Ubuntu 18.04.

When I `$ curl -v majlovesreg.one` it returns okay. But when I add **www**, `$ curl -v www.majlovesreg.one`  **within the server** it throws the error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.majlovesreg.one`.

What is interesting is when `$ curl -v www.majlovesreg.one` is invoked from **outside the server** (i.e. my home computer) it returns okay.

Also, `dig` and `nslookup` for [www.majlovesreg.one](https://www.majlovesreg.one/) within the server both return okay. (This cURL error by the way is preventing WordPress from performing its own `wp-cron` tasks.)

Can someone please nudge me on the right direction on how to troubleshoot this problem? This looks like a cURL problem. Thank you!